# HOW to append pg_restore restoration log to file

Tags: command-line, postgresql-9.4, pg-restore, output-redirect

I have tried multiple way to append log but not able to get.

for example.

```
pg_restore -U postgres -p5333 -d demodb < db_bkp_01_10_2019.dump >db_bkp_01_10_2019.log

pg_restore -U postgres -p5333 -d demodb < db_bkp_01_10_2019.dump 2>db_bkp_01_10_2019.log

pg_restore -U postgres -p5333 -d demodb < db_bkp_01_10_2019.dump 2&>db_bkp_01_10_2019.log
```

I want log  related to restoration like what command executed on db while restoration.

Comment: Use `>>` instead of `>`

Comment: When i use >> instead of > getting log output on screen where i have fired command of restoration  and nothing is showing in log , demodb_backup]$ cat db_bkp_01_10_2019.log

Comment: Also i used this command pg_restore -U postgres -p5333 -d demodb <db_bkp_01_10_2019.dump >db_bkp_01_10_2019.log 2>&1 using this i get log into file db_bkp_01_10_2019.log still i am getting logs also on screen where i fired restore command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the --verbose

Try this command

./pg_restore -U postgres -p 5333 -d demodb < db_bkp_01_10_2019.dump --verbose 2>db_bkp_01_10_2019.log

Answer (score 0):

Took me sometime to figure this out, it works for me in psql 11 for log:

```
$pg_restore -h 127.0.0.1 -U user -p 5432 -d dbname -Fc import_data.sql>import.log 2>&1
```